# Is there a way to request Youtube to display a pre-roll ad?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is there some kind of url parameter (or whatever) that tell Youtube to display a pre-roll ad?
I need it for debugging my extension, currently I need to play videos till I finally get a pre-roll ad to check my new code change and it takes way too much time...

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing your cookies before/after each test.  Most ads have frequency caps that only allow you to watch certain ads x times per day, but if YouTube doesn't know who you are or what ads you've seen, they can't enforce those caps.  This means you wouldn't want to be logged in to YouTube while testing as well...

Comment: Tried both those options, seems to help a little (after spending some time testing) but what I want is a way to make Youtube display a pre-roll ad each time I want it to (preferably in a debug mode so the advertiser wont pay for it).